# Laravel 6 - Show name, zip code instead of IDs in Blade

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm a beginner in Laravel, I need to show a name instead of an ID in Laravel blade.

These are the tables in the database:

**city:**

```
+----+--------+
| id | name   |
+----+--------+
|  1 | Vienna |
|  2 | Linz   |
+----+--------+
```

**zip:**

```
+----+---------+------+-------------+
| id | city_id | code | name        |
+----+---------+------+-------------+
|  1 |       1 | 1010 | 1. district |
|  2 |       1 | 1020 | 2. district |
|  3 |       1 | 1030 | 3. district |
|  4 |       2 | 4020 | Linz        |
+----+---------+------+-------------+
```

**street:**

```
+----+--------+---------------+
| id | zip_id | name          |
+----+--------+---------------+
|  1 |      1 | Burgring      |
|  2 |      1 | Seilergasse   |
|  3 |      2 | Praterstrasse |
+----+--------+---------------+
```

**orders:**

```
+----+---------+------+-----+--------+
| id | orderno | city | zip | street |
+----+---------+------+-----+--------+
|  1 | 100001  | 1    | 2   | 3      |
|  2 | 100002  | 1    | 1   | 2      |
|  3 | 100003  | 1    | 1   | 1      |
+----+---------+------+-----+--------+
```

Controller:

```
$orders = Order::all();
return view('orders-show', compact('orders'));
```

Blade:

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
    <tr>
        <td>{{$order->id}}</td>
        <td>{{$order->orderno}}</td>
        <td>{{$order->city}}</td>
        <td>{{$order->zip}}</td>
        <td>{{$order->street}}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

Result:
[image: Result]

The result I expect:
[image: expected result]

I believe there is a much better way than to create a view function for each item.
As I read it, I suppose that through Model, can connect city, zip and street, something like **belongsTo** and **hasMany**.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it using [One To Many](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships#one-to-many-inverse) relationship.

First of all, update your `orders` table to use [Eloquent Relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-relationships) properly:

```
+----+---------+---------+--------+-----------+
| id | orderno | city_id | zip_id | street_id |
+----+---------+---------+--------+-----------+
|  1 | 100001  | 1       | 2      | 3         |
|  2 | 100002  | 1       | 1      | 2         |
|  3 | 100003  | 1       | 1      | 1         |
+----+---------+---------+--------+-----------+
```

**1. Define a relationship between `city` and `zip` tables:**

Add this to your `zip` table migration:

```
$table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('city')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Then, define `city()` method in your `Zip` model class:

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
}
```

**2. Define a relationship between `zip` and `street` tables:**

Add this to your `street` table migration:

```
$table->foreign('zip_id')->references('id')->on('zip')->onDelete('cascade');
```

Then, define `zip()` method in your `Street` model class:

```
public function zip()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Zip');
}
```

**3. Define a relationship between `city`, `zip`, `street` and `orders` tables:**

Add these lines to your `orders` table migration:

```
$table->foreign('city_id')->references('id')->on('city');
$table->foreign('zip_id')->references('id')->on('zip');
$table->foreign('street_id')->references('id')->on('street');
```

Then, define a method for each of these relationships in your `Order` model class:

```
public function city()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\City');
}

public function zip()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Zip');
}

public function street()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Street');
}
```

**4. Now use them in your view (blade):**

```
@foreach($orders as $order)
    <tr>
        <td>{{ $order->id }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->orderno }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->city['name'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->zip['code'] }}</td>
        <td>{{ $order->street['name'] }}</td>
    </tr>
@endforeach
```

---

**Note:** Table names are plural by default in Laravel Eloquent. If you want to keep your table names singular, do not forget to set the `$table` property inside of your models. For example, in your `City` model class:

```
protected $table = 'city';
```